# ARM926 USB Power management

Tags: linux, usb, arm, power-management

I have some starter kit board based on Atmel ARM926 400MH. Powered by linux.

And I need to control power of USB, i.e. switch it off and switch it off.

I try to research for use sysfs, but there is no information about switching on/off.

Comment: Depends entirely on the board you're using. There's a significant chance it's not possible at all -- USB power is often pulled directly from the board's 5V regulator.

Comment: If there are multiple ports, odds there's a USB Hub with integrated power control. However, USB power management is not usually exposed to user-space per se - I can't think of a single application where you would normally want it.

Answer (score 0):

You either can’t control USB power, or the OS will control it for you.  As noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631997/1821972), “... users shouldn't be conscious of this layer.”

Port power might be hardwired to be always present, but more often hardware allows control by the driver.  One example I’ve seen, host port through a 3320 USB PHY should have port power automatically enabled by CPEN output.

This area was enhanced with runtime power management framework introduced in 2.6.32 kernel.  Details can depend on SoC and specific board support.  New features can allow user space control to prevent auto suspend and resulting powerdown;  otherwise, by default, USB should power down in suspend modes.

Lots more info in [Regupathy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435457862).