# OSX / UNIX command to initialize USB devices

Tags: macos, unix, command, usb, hardware

I use a 3-Port-USB-Ethernet-Hub. Everytime I start my MacBook, all USB-devices connected to the hub work easily. But the ethernet-connection is not recognized, so I have to unplug and replug the whole hub every single time. Afterwards everything works well, including internet-connection.
Does anybody know an option to "initialize" which means automatically unplug and replug all USB-devices software-wise e.g. using an UNIX-command and run a script after booting?

Thank you!

Martin

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163824/linux-usb-turning-the-power-on-and-off.

Comment: I already found that. But that's for linux. Those commands do not work on OSX. How do I address a USB-device if it's not a volume?

Comment: Then what about http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59764/how-to-disable-individual-usb-ports-by-script

Comment: Ok, now I know the product ID, but what next? Sorry for asking so much, but all those commands do not work for me on OS X.